# Moving strings into register with a loop 8051 assembly

Tags: assembly, 8051

This code below successfully moves a given string into a register, in this case, register 1; using r2 as a counter. However, r2 has to be hardcoded with the length of the string for the loop to finalize correctly. Is it possible to implement a similar solution without hardcoding a counter?

```
ORG     100H
            MOV     R2, #13D
                MOV R1, #0
                MOV     DPTR,#DAT0
    AGAIN:      MOV     A, R1
            MOVC    A, @ A+DPTR
            MOV P1, A
            INC     R1
            DJNZ    R2, AGAIN
            SJMP    $
DAT0:       DB  "(C) XYZ Inc.",0
    END
```

Comment: Of course it is possible. Just check whether you loaded a zero.

Comment: Hrm, you are not "moving the string into register R1". The register R1 is used as the offset into the string, which is copied character by character to port P1. -- Anyway, you can look at R2 and DPTR as parameters, and so @Jester is right: It is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you **don't want to send the terminating zero byte to P1**, then jump out of the loop with the `JZ` instruction that jumps if the accumulator `A` contains zero:

```
  ORG     100h
  MOV     R2, #0       ; Offset in string
  MOV     DPTR, #DAT0  ; Start of string
More:
  MOV     A, R2
  MOVC    A, @A+DPTR   ; Get character of the string
  JZ      Done         ; JUMPS IF A==0
  MOV     P1, A        ; Send A to P1 (excluding 0)
  INC     R2
  SJMP    More
Done:
  SJMP    $
DAT0:     DB  "(C) XYZ Inc.",0
  END
```

If you **do want to send the terminating zero byte to P1**, then only loop back if the last byte send was non-zero. Use the `JNZ` instruction that jumps if the accumulator `A` contains anything but zero:

```
  ORG     100h
  MOV     R2, #0       ; Offset in string
  MOV     DPTR, #DAT0  ; Start of string
More:
  MOV     A, R2
  MOVC    A, @A+DPTR   ; Get character of the string
  MOV     P1, A        ; Send A to P1 (including 0)
  INC     R2
  JNZ     More         ; DOESN'T JUMP IF A==0
  SJMP    $
DAT0:     DB  "(C) XYZ Inc.",0
  END
```